# TypeScript syntax explanation, optional parameters

Tags: typescript, syntax, optional-parameters

I recently came across the following function declaration

```
subscribe(observerOrNext?: PartialObserver<T> | ((value: T) => void), error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
```

I understand that '?' means optional , but what does the rest mean, especially the 
: `PartialObserver<T> | ((value: T) => void)` part?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the pipe(|) mean in typescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628115/what-does-the-pipe-mean-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that '?' means optional , but what does the rest mean,
>   especially the : `PartialObserver<T> | ((value: T) => void)` part?

The char **'|'** is known as **[Union Type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)** and is used here to tell that the `observerOrNext`parameter can be one of the foolowing type:

- generic type `PartialObserver<T>`
- or a callback function which signature must return nothing e.g. `void` and accept a parameter `value` of type `T`.

The TypeScript [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) for **Advanced Types** explains in a better way when to use **Union Type**.