# TypeScript: Enforce consistent object key as type parameter

Tags: typescript

I have a `Column` interface that can render values from rows based on the keys:

```
interface Column<Row, Field extends keyof Row> {
    key: Field;
    render: (value: Row[Field]) => React.ReactNode;
}
```

If I explicitly set the type of each column, then I get the desired behaviour. For instance, the following is invalid:

```
interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

const column: Column<User, "id"> = {
    key: "id",
    render(id: string) {
        return id;
    }
};
```

since the `id` property is a string, not a number. Is there a way to get this behaviour without having to specify the type of each column individually? For instance, the following type-checks:

```
const columns: Array<Column<User, keyof User>> = [
    {
        key: "id",
        render(id: string) {
            return id;
        }
    }
];
```

since `Field` is instantiated to `keyof User`, rather than a specific key.

Comment: How about union type:
 id: number | string;
have a look:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628115/what-does-the-pipe-mean-in-typescript

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps: I want TypeScript to only allow `id: number` as the argument.

Comment: ohh, OK. didn't understand your question though.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I love this type of question.  One problem you're running into is that TypeScript won't let you leave out type parameters and [infer their types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14400).  You want to say something like `Column<User>` where the `Row` type parameter is inferred from the object literal you pass to it.  Well, we can't do that directly... but we can get this effect indirectly:

```
function columnsFor<Row>() {
  function of<Field extends keyof Row>(column: Column<Row, Field>): Column<Row, Field> {
    return column;
  }
  return of;
}
```

The function `columnsFor` is sort of a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function; you can explicitly set the `Row` type parameter, and it returns another function that accepts objects of `Column<Row,Field>` for *any* valid type of `Field`.  Here's how you'd use it:

```
const userColumn = columnsFor<User>();    

const goodColumn = userColumn({
  key: "id",
  render(id: number) {
    return id;
  }
}); // ok, inferred as Column<User, "id">

const badColumn = userColumn({
  key: "id",
  render(id: string) {
    return id;
  }
}); // error as expected
```

The `userColumn` function will only accept an argument of some `Column<User, Field>` type, and infers `Field` from that argument.  Now you can go ahead and make that array:

```
const columns = [
  userColumn({
    key: "id",
    render(id: number) {
      return id;
    }
  }), // ok, inferred as Column<User,"id">
  userColumn({
    key: "name",
    render(name: string) {
      return name;
    }
  }), // ok, inferred as Column<User,"name">
  userColumn({
    key: "id",
    render(id: string) {
      return id;
    }
  }) // error as expected
];
```

Hope that's useful to you.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I suspected something like this might be possible, but I wasn't sure what the idiomatic approach in TypeScript would be. I was hoping there'd be a way to guarantee correct usage using the type system, since it's still possible to produce incorrect code. You could do that using this approach if TypeScript had opaque types by making `Column` opaque, so that all columns have to be created using `columnFor`.

Comment: You could make `Column` a class with a private constructor and give it a static method to produce only the `Column` objects you want.  And the code above isn't exactly incorrect; you told TypeScript you wanted an array of `Column<User, "id"|"name">`, which isn't really what you meant.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at private constructors. As for the original code not being incorrect: I reckon the column isn't a valid instance of `Column<User, "id|"name">` since the `render` method doesn't handle both cases. I think the only reason it type-checks is because of TypeScript's (unsound) bivariant function parameters.