# Inferred type in generic with multiple type parameters

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript2.0

I am trying to setup a generic where the parameter is the key of another object. I can accomplish this using `extends keyof` when both types are parameters are to the function.

However when the type providing the list of keys is not an argument, just a generic type, typescript requires both generic types to be set.

Consider the following code:

```
interface Bar {
  z: string;
  t: number;
}

declare function foo1<T extends keyof Bar>(x: T)
let t1 = foo1('z');

declare function foo2<K, T extends keyof K>(x: T)
let t2 = foo2<Bar>('t');

declare function foo3<T>(x: T)
let t3 = foo3<keyof Bar>('t');
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Bar%20%7B%0A%20%20z%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20t%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Adeclare%20function%20foo1%3CT%20extends%20keyof%20Bar%3E(x%3A%20T)%0Alet%20t1%20%3D%20foo1('z')%3B%0A%0Adeclare%20function%20foo2%3CK%2C%20T%20extends%20keyof%20K%3E(x%3A%20T)%0Alet%20t2%20%3D%20foo2%3CBar%3E('t')%3B%0A%0Adeclare%20function%20foo3%3CT%3E(x%3A%20T)%0Alet%20t3%20%3D%20foo3%3Ckeyof%20Bar%3E('t')%3B%0A)

Function `foo2` fails since the second type `T` is not specified. However I feel like TS should be able to infer the correct typings without an explicit second type.

`foo3` is my workaround, but isn't as nice to work with, is it possible to have typescript perform this inference, or will this be a feature request / bug report to the TS team?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close with `foo2`. Here is what it's supposed to be to make it work.

```
declare function foo2<T, K = keyof T>(x: K)
let t2 = foo2<Bar>('t');
```

Instead of expecting a new generic type parameter, you can assign one to a type (in this case the type of `T`).

It's also possible to directly assign the paramaters type to the `keyof` the given generic type `T`.

```
declare function foo4<T>(x: keyof T);
let t4 = foo4<Bar>('t');
```

Comment: Thank you for this option. It is unfortunate that it will not allow strict typing checking since K could be explicitly passed and be incompatible with T.

Comment: @Arjes You can also directly do `func<T>(x: keyof T)`.

Comment: That is perfect and will ensure typesaftey in the same way. Doing it two levels deep is dirty though! `func<T>(x: keyof T, y: keyof T[typeof x])` but there are not compiler warnings! I wish I had the reputation to upvote ya.

Answer (score 2):

There is already an outstanding suggestion for partial inference of type parameters (without using defaults) at [Microsoft/TypeScript#14400](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14400).  For now, you can't do that.  Instead, I will give you a [workaround that I often suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46242868/2887218) in cases like this: [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) functions.

```
declare function curriedFoo<B>(): <T extends keyof B>(x: T)=>any;
let t4 = curriedFoo<Bar>()('t'); // okay
```

The no-argument function `curriedFoo()` takes a type parameter `B` (I can't use `K` for anything but a key, sorry), and returns a function of the type you really want, narrowed to only accepting a `T extends keyof B` parameter (here's where I'd want to use `K`, but never mind).

It's a bit clumsy but it gets the job done.  Hope that helps; good luck!