# Typescript weird type

Tags: typescript

I've come across this type:

```
let a: [number | string];
```

I've googled and looked at the Typescript docs but I don't see this syntax mentioned.  What is it, I see the base is a union of string or number but it's not a tuple nor is it an array.  What does it correspond to?  Can anyone explain in simple terms and how to initialise it and add values please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the pipe(|) mean in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628115/what-does-the-pipe-mean-in-typescript)

Comment: Looks like a tuple of only one item, where that item is either a string or a number. Valid values might be: `[1]` or `["somestring"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It **is** a tuple of size 1. Contains either a `number` or a `string`

Comment: I think the API doc for the valeu is confusing me as it says it is [string|number]  - and so I init'd it by <[string]>[];  but it only accepts values and works as described if I pass it a string[].  Anyway I think you are correct it is simply just an 'odd' single element tuple.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would describe this as an [array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array) that can only hold a single item, which has to be either a number or a string.

You can also describe the array as a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), but personally I feel that the entire point of tuples is that they should hold multiple values, rather than just one.
Both are correct.

*Sidenote: When I run into an unfamiliar syntax, I like to try them out in the typescript sandbox and look at the generated javascript code: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/*

Comment: I tried that website but it just converts it as `var a`.  Still useful to use in future thank you.

Comment: Sorry, you're right that in this case the generated javascript code isn't very useful. I meant it more as a way of experimentation. For example, [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20a%3A%20%5Bnumber%20%7C%20string%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FWorks%0D%0Aa%20%3D%20%5B1%5D%3B%0D%0Aa%20%3D%20%5B%22text%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FDoesn't%20work%0D%0Aa%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%20%22text%22%5D%3B%0D%0Aa%20%3D%20%221%22%3B%0D%0Aa%20%3D%201%3B) will give you some insight in what's possible and isn't, without needing a development environment.