# If "keyof (A|B)" is "never", why is "excess property checking" happy when I use a key from A or B?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to understand Typescript types more in depth, I find the following behavior confusing:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
}
interface Lifespan {
    birth: number;
    death?: number;
}

let k: keyof (Person | Lifespan); //k is never
let test1: Person | Lifespan = { randomKey: 123 }; //I understand the error: Object literal may only specify known properties (because keyof is never)
let test2: Person | Lifespan = { name: "A Name" }; //No error given which is confusing, where does test2 get "name" property from?
```

Is this an oversight / attempt at being helpful somehow - by the excess property checking? When the keyof of an union is never, I don't understand why TypeScript thinks "name" has a special meaning here.

Comment: That's a union type - `test2` can be or `Person` or `Lifespan` (so `{ name: "A Name" }` is valid here). `keyof (Person | Lifespan) ` is `never` because they don't have common properties

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think thinking of union as OR is a bit simplistic in the depths of TS type system. It can also be "both" so `let test2: Person | Lifespan = { name: "asd", birth: 3 };` is also valid (incorporating keys from both) so TS recognises that `Person | Lifespan` combo _can_ have name, birth, death but if we query the keys of that type within the type system, it gives never - yet excess property checking somehow knows about those keys - which is what I find confusing.

Comment: No, union is `or`.  Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628115/what-does-the-pipe-mean-in-typescript/38628264#38628264. More info here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html. Both is intersection. Regarding `let test2: Person | Lifespan = { name: "asd", birth: 3 };` - it is allowed because of structural type system.

Comment: And it is the "structural type system" that I'm trying to build intuition about. That's why I'm chasing the apparent inconsistencies because I believe they expose holes in my intuition. Instead of thinking of "OR" when I see `|` I think about set theory because it fits better with how TS interprets things. For instance `type X = unknown | number;` is unknown, not `unknown OR number` because unknown set consumes number. With object properties neither my set analogy nor your OR analogy works though. "It is allowed because of STS" is a bit handwavy - no offense intended.

Comment: A type `T` is assignable to a union type `U` if `T` is assignable to at least one of the constituents of `U`. Back to your example - `{ name: "asd", birth: 3 }` is assignable both to `Person`  and `Lifespan ` Hope that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since this question was opened but I hope this answer it's still useful. I'm not very familiar with TypeScript implementation however you mentioned that you want to improve your intuition around the types so maybe this still helps.

First the `|` operator can be seen as an `or` or as a union (of sets), both interpretations are compatible from an algebraic point of view. Remember that the union of the sets `A` and `B` is the set containing every element in `A` *or* in `B`:

```
x ∈ A ∪ B ≡ {x : x ∈ A ∨ x ∈ B}
```

Where `∨` is the logical "or".

Similarly, a given value is of type `A | B` if (and only if) it is of type `A` *or* `B`. The case "or both" is already included since that's the definition of a logical "or"; is an *inclusive or*, not *exclusive*. So `A | B` is the *union* of types `A` and `B` since is defined in terms of the logical `or`.

Back to TypeScript. What the type checker does when we *declare* a value of a union or *observe* such a value is covered in [the spec](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md). It's not been updated in a while but the basics are the same. [§3.4](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#34-union-types) covers union types and [§3.11.1](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.11.1) covers *apparent member*, that could be very useful for understanding what a union "looks like" depending on the use.

When we declare a variable of a union type and assign a value to it, TypeScript will check that the value can be assigned to *any* of the constituent types of the union (or both, but there's no need to say that):

```
let t1: Person | Lifespan = { name: '' }; // OK
let t2: Person | Lifespan = { death: 0 }; // Error
let t3: Person | Lifespan = { name: '', birth: 0 }; // Also OK
let t4: Person | Lifespan = { hungriness: 100 }; // WAT? (Error)
```

The checker accepts the values for `t1` and `t3` since the types of those objects are assignable to at least one of the constituents. For `t2` at least the property `birth` is missing and `t3` is not assignable to any of them. TypeScript can perform excess property checking because, in the example, we are trying to assign from a *fresh* object.

But the types "looks" different when we are trying to "consume" them, when we *observe* such a type. For instance:

```
function foo(param: Person | Lifespan) {
  let name = param.name; // Error
}
```

The error here is very reasonable. We are trying to access a property that exists in only one of the constituents types yet `param` is declared as a union and we don't know (without checking) which one is the right value (or if the value has properties of both). We are observing the type and the *apparent members* of that union are those properties that are present in *every* constituent of the union, otherwise the access is unsafe. The types `Person` and `Lifespan` have no keys in common so TypeScript won't let us access any of them. The types looks much like an *intersection* (`A & B`).

Let's consider the next snippet:

```
type T1 = keyof (Person | Lifespan);
type T2 = keyof Person & keyof Lifespan;
type T3 = keyof (Person & Lifespan);
type T4 = keyof Person | keyof Lifespan;
```

Here we're also *observing* the types, so `keyof (Person | Lifespan)` looks for those apparent members and found none. In the example `T1` and `T2` are both `never`, confirming that when you observe a union type it "looks a lot like" an intersection. Don't take this phrase to seriously, though. The spec does explain this more rigorously. Oh and the types `T3` and `T4` are both `"name" | "birth" | "death"`.

For an intersection type the cases are analogous to these: a type `T` is *assignable to* the intersection type `A & B` if `T` is assignable to *each* of them, to `A` *and* `B`. But the intersection type `A & B` is assignable to a type `T` if *any* of them, `A` *or* `B`, is assignable to `T`.

Hope this helps to clarify a little.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're conflating two aspects of the type here: how it's *created* vs how it's *used*.

A union type `A | B` is easier to *create* than its parts. You can *create* a `Person | Lifespan` from either a `Person` or `Lifespan`; it doesn't matter which. But it's harder to *use*: any code that takes a `Person | Lifespan` has to handle both cases, not just one.

The other types can be understood in the same way. Intersection types `A & B` are harder to create but easier to use (the opposite of unions); the `null` type is very easy to create but has no use; and the `never` type is impossible to create but can be used as anything.

In this framework, we can understand `keyof` as a statement on how a type can be *used*. Hence, when applied to the union type `Person | Lifespan`, the question is not

> What properties are available on either `Person` or `Lifespan`?

but

> If I know that a value is either a `Person` or `Lifespan`, but I don't know which, then what properties am I guaranteed to have?

The answer to that question, of course, is nothing at all. So `keyof (Person | Lifespan)` is `never`.