# Declaring a variable, without using "any" with different Data Types/Interfaces

Tags: typescript

How can I declare a specific set of data types to my variable?

I don't want to use "any" I feel like it will affect the performance of my app.

for example

```
myVariable: Interface1, Interface2, Interface3;
```

Comment: You mean variable can be Interface1 or 2 or 3? Then you can use union type: `let myVariable: Interface1 | Interface2 | Interface3;` https://stackoverflow.com/a/38628264/1113002

Comment: In terms of runtime performance, `any` has no affect since TS just compiles to JS and all type annotations are removed.