# typescript interface being string or object

Tags: typescript, interface

Can I define an interface that is either string or some object? What I need is to create an interface for a message which can be
`"Lorem ipsum"`
or

```
{
   a: 1,
   b: 2
}
```

Comment: `string | WhateverYourObjectIs` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the pipe(|) mean in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628115/what-does-the-pipe-mean-in-typescript)

Comment: your solution is for type defining, I'm asking about interface. Is there a way to declare an interface like that?

Comment: No: 1. Interfaces cannot be primitives 2. Interfaces cannot be unions - only one single thing.

Comment: Great! That's what I wanted to know! Thank you :)

Comment: @VLAZ This gives me an error "Property x does not exist on type 'string | myObject'" even tho it exists on myObject

Comment: @AlxVallejo because you're probably trying to set a property on the union. And one of the items in the union (the string) doesn't declare that property exists. Therefore, the code would be wrong when your data is a string. [Narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type or just don't use a union here. You usually don't want to be in the situation where you code *might* work half the time or *might* be an error the other half. And setting a property on a union that doesn't necessarily have that property is that kind of situaton.